# /s/ or /z/ in exacerbate

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Today, someone asked me if the pronunciation of the "c" in "exacerbate" is an /s/ or a /z/. In fast speech, it seems indistinguishable if I substitute /z/ for the /s/ , which is the standard dictionary pronunciation).

Are both pronunciations acceptable? I did some digging and discovered that between two vowel sounds, the phoneme is voiced (reason, cousin, teasing) , but I'm not sure if this is a hard and fast rule.

Comment: Have you looked up exacerbate in a dictionary? Seems they have /s/. Reason, cousin, tease are all pronounced /z/ not /s/, as a dictionary will tell you - it's not a question of them having an /s/ which is sometimes voiced, they have a /z/. But there are no hard and fast rules linking spelling and pronunciation.

Comment: Haha, I'd be more triggered by the "ex" at the start being pronounced "eggs". But I call these sound changes "sandhi", and whether I like them or not in english, they are a standard phenomenon in language, and can't be called "wrong" (but can be called "irritating"!)

Comment: @StuartF looked it up and saw it was /s/, but yeah… I wonder..

Comment: No matter how fast I say "exacerbate," it's fairly clear that the sound is S and distinguishable from Z.

Comment: Well, it ain't exazerbate. zero is not sero.

Comment: When I say it very quickly, I also replace the /s/ with a /z/. Hrm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the usual pronunciation of *exacerbate*, *c* is pronounced as /s/.

There is absolutely no rule saying the phoneme /s/ is replaced with /z/ between two vowel sounds.

The words "reason, cousin, teasing" are examples of the letter (not phoneme) ⟨s⟩ being used to represent the sound /z/ between two vowel letters. That is common, but it is not a rule either: to list just a few exceptions, *goose, crease, cease* always have /s/ and *glucose, basic, evasive* usually have /s/.

Voiceless phonemes can sometimes have some phonetic voicing (this occurs not just in English but in all kinds of languages). Maybe that is why you find that it doesn't sound different in fast speech if you use /s/ or /z/ in *exacerbate*.

Comment: Could you link me to a good site that talks about phonetic voicing for voiceless phonemes?

Comment: @meepyer: Sorry, I'm not sure I know of one. I think I was basing my comments partly on the article [A voice for the voiceless: Production and perception of assimilated stops in French](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0095447005000380) which is mainly about French and is largely technical. There are some other articles like that I've read but I don't know of a good introduction to the concept.

Comment: Thanks! No worries. It’s been a while since I took any phonetics classes but it’s still helpful to know.